# What is in Angular 2 Opaque Token and What's the Point?

Tags: angular, angular2-opaquetoken

I am running into 'opaque tokens' as a solution to implementing global constants in Angular 2, for example here: [Define global constants in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants-in-angular-2/40287063#40287063)

Despite reading the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html), I can't seem to grasp the point.

> Using an OpaqueToken is preferable to using strings as tokens because
>   of possible collisions caused by multiple providers using the same
>   string as two different tokens.

What? What's an Angular2 token to begin with? All I get on google are answers on JSON Web Tokens (their role in auth, etc, etc), which I understand, but are obviously not related in any way.

What's an Opaque Token? What is it used for?

P.S. More [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens) on opaque tokens as used to provide constants. They didn't help me very much, however.

Comment: Why didn't that help? That's exactly what they're for.

Comment: I don't get what a 'token' is in this context, at all.

Comment: *"Input elements other than white space and comments... reserved words, identifiers, literals, and punctuators..."* - https://ariya.io/2012/07/most-popular-javascript-tokens. Here's a good example of use of an `OpaqueToken`; injecting the `LOCALE_ID`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39344889/3001761

Comment: Yep, more or less. If they'd just done `export const LOCALE_ID = 'localeId';` or something, there'd be no way for the DI to distinguish it from the same constant elsewhere.

Comment: Think of 'token' as of a synonym to 'identifier'. And `OpaqueToken` is A2-specific alternative to `Symbol`. If you know what `Symbol` is for, you already know the deal.

Comment: Is there a practical reason for this A2 specific alternative, or do you get the same result by exporting a plain old ES6 Symbol? (Trying it now...)

Comment: I don't see a reason not to just import a constants.ts file and be done tbh.

Comment: @VSO Genuinely curious -- was there a reason you felt Gunter's answer wasn't "check worthy"? Anything you felt was missing?

Comment: @ruffin To be honest, I don't remember now. I will come back to review it. Usually I do check answers though, so I am guessing there was a reason. P.S. Gunter is an awesome expert, so I am sure he is correct. I will come back to this.

Answer (score 68):

**update Angular4**

In Angular4 `OpaqueToken` is deprecated and will be replaced by `InjectionToken`.
InjectionToken allows to pass a generic type parameter.

```ts
export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<MyConfig>("app.config");
```

See also

- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html
- [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20170107033143/https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html) (no longer live; rerouted to archive.org version)

**original**

> What? What's an Angular2 token to begin with?
>
> What's an Opaque Token? What is it used for?

A token is a key for providers of Angulars dependency injection.
Providers are registered with a key and components, directives, and service classes instantiated by DI get dependencies injected which are looked up by provider keys.

DI supports types, strings, `OpaqueToken` and objects as keys.

```ts
export let APP_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken("app.config");

export let APP_CONFIG_2 = {};

providers: [
  MyService, // type is key and value
  {provide: MyService, useClass: MyFancyServiceImpl}, // type is key, `MyFancyServiceImpl` is the value (or rather the information how to create the value
  {provide: 'myservice', useClass: MyService}, // key is a string
  {provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: {a: 'a', b: 'b'}} // key is an `OpaqueToken`
  {provide: APP_CONFIG_2, useValue: {a: 'a', b: 'b'}} // key is an object

]
```

```ts
// one of these decorators needs to be added to make DI work
@Injectable()
@Component()
@Directive()
@Pipe()
class MyComponent {
  // DI looks up a provider registered with the key `MyService` 
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {} 

  // Same as before but explicit
  constructor(@Inject(MyService) private myService: MyService) {} 

  // DI looks up a provider registered with the key 'myService'
  constructor(@Inject('myservice') private myService: MyService) {} 

  // DI looks up a provider registered with the `OpaqueKey` `APP_CONFIG`
  constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private myConfig: any) {} 

  // DI looks up a provider registered with the object `APP_CONFIG_2`
  constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG_2) private myConfig: any) {}
```

The object key (`APP_CONFIG_2`) and the `OpaqueToken` (`APP_CONFIG`) need to be the exact same instance. A different instance with the same content won't work. This makes it easy to look up where the key is declared and whether the provider and the injection target use the same key.

For a string it can be a different instance, this brings the risk, that the same string value is used in different modules and might cause conflicts or the wrong provider being injected.

Comment: you are always the first with most detailed answer! :)

Comment: @StepanSuvorov I try as far as my time allows. Glad to hear you think it's a good answer :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Not sure if I am wasting your time with saying thanks, but I appreciate it!

Comment: Perhaps this sounds dumb, but whats the difference between this and saving the 'global constant' in a file which will be included all over my app? Is it to making testing easier by utilizing DI? Or are there any other good reasons for it.

Comment: This article (or maybe finally REALLY needing to use this outside of tests helped me too): https://medium.com/@michelestieven/angular-writing-configurable-modules-69e6ea23ea42

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how about Angualr 8

Answer (score 4):

> What's an Opaque Token? What is it used for?

Opaque Token used for inject another provider(service) with same name.

This allows you to avoid naming collisions.

```js
     const MY_HTTP_TOKEN: OpaqueToken = new OpaqueToken('Http');

     providers: [
        { provide: MY_HTTP_TOKEN, useClass: Http }
     ]

     constructor(@Inject(MY_HTTP_TOKEN) private myHttpService){}
```

Comment: This is a pretty useful reply now that I am looking at it. Helps explain why you would even bother.

Answer (score 4):

An Opaque Token is just a runtime class that is used as a unique identifier for injector providers.

Lets say you have a value, 'secretId' that you want to use into a few services and components. You don't want to hard code this in your services and components, as it will change in the future. As well you want to write tests for your services and components.

With a class you can use the class as an implementation, type and injector token. For a string value, other literal expressions, objects, etc -- you have nothing to use as an injector token. You could use a string as an injector token, but there is no garuntee that string will be unique. With Opaque tokens, even if two tokens have the same name, they will be evaluated as different tokens.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to angular 2, but I want to try to interpret what I understood from https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html in a simple code. CMIIW.

```
...
const CONFIG_ONE = {title: 'My awesome app'};
let configOneToken = 'config';  //'config' is an example of string-type token

const CONFIG_TWO = {title: 'My fantastic app'};
let configTwoToken = 'config';

providers = [
  { provide: configOneToken, useValue: CONFIG_ONE },
  { provide: configTwoToken, useValue: CONFIG_TWO }
];
```

That piece of code will have an issue (the later will override the former) because it has conflict (`'config' == 'config'`).
It may be too obvious and meaningless in that toy code, but in a real code, we may not be able to identify this conflict easily when one of the provider is defined in a third party library.
So, to fix that, we can use OpaqueToken as in the following code.

```
...
const CONFIG_ONE = {title: 'My awesome app'};
const OPAQUE_TOKEN_ONE = new OpaqueToken('config'); //this is an example of object-type token

const CONFIG_TWO = {title: 'My fantastic app'};
const OPAQUE_TOKEN_TWO = new OpaqueToken('config');

providers = [
  { provide: OPAQUE_TOKEN_ONE, useValue: CONFIG_ONE },
  { provide: OPAQUE_TOKEN_TWO, useValue: CONFIG_TWO }
];
```

Two instances of any same class are never be equal (`new OpaqueToken('config') != new OpaqueToken('config')`) and therefor avoiding conflict. The `OpaqueToken` itself is nothing but just as a simple doing-nothing class.