# Receiving 'resolving symbol values statically' related error message when compiling Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, compilation, angular2-services

I am using some old module: `angular-2-local-storage`.
The way it's being instantiated is the following:

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG_TOKEN: string = 'LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG';
export const LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken(LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG_TOKEN);
```

... and further in my code:

```
@NgModule({
  .....
  providers: [
      LocalStorageService,
    {
      provide: LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG,
      useValue: { prefix: 'miswap' }
    },
    {
```

But when building my project, I receive this:

***Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler (position 2:22 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG in ....***

This is where I am totally lost.

The issue looks like OpaqueToken deprecation as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289264/what-is-in-angular-2-opaque-token-and-whats-the-point). However, my project is Angular 2, not 4.

So, do I miss something? Is this because of some angular cli version wrong? Don't even know where to find solution!

This is part of my `package.json` if that might help:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "0.3.0",
    "@types/async": "2.0.31",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.32",
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:
What is the value of `LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG` before providing it? Try `console.log(LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG)` right before declaration of the `@NgModule`. If its `undefined`, you are either not importing it properly, so the value is missing, or there is a problem with `new OpaqueToken()` - is OpaqueToken undefined?

Comment: I am not sure where you would want me to run `console.log` as this is not my app runtime error. The app itself functioning well when launched (in dev, and old version of prod). However, I receive it when forcing gulp build.dev.exp. And the error itself rather referring to semantics, I guess.