# "Can't resolve all parameters for service: (?)" when I try to use service from library in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10, injectable

In my library I have a service with this code:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataInjectorModule } from '../../data-injector.module';

// @dynamic
@Injectable()
export class RemoteDataService<T> {
  @Inject('env') private environment: any = {};
  public type: new () => T;
  
  constructor(
    model: T,
  ) {
    this.http = DataInjectorModule.InjectorInstance.get(HttpClient);
  }

  // ...
}
```

The `data-injector.module` (existing reason is only avoid circular dependency):

```js
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';

// @dynamic
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class DataInjectorModule {
  static InjectorInstance: Injector;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    DataInjectorModule.InjectorInstance = injector;
  }

}
```

In my library's main module file:

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { DataInjectorModule } from './data-injector.module';
import { RemoteDataService } from './services/remote-data/remote-data.service';

// @dynamic
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    DataInjectorModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class DataCoreModule {
  static InjectorInstance: Injector;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    DataCoreModule.InjectorInstance = injector;
  }

  public static forRoot(environment: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: DataCoreModule,
      providers: [
        RemoteDataService,
        { provide: 'env', useValue: environment }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Finally in my application's `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { DataCoreModule } from 'data-core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DdataCoreModule.forRoot(environment),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Build goes well, but in the browser I get this error:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RemoteDataService: (?).
    at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (core.js:11338)
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (core.js:11328)
    at providerToFactory (core.js:11371)
    at providerToRecord (core.js:11358)
    at R3Injector.processProvider (core.js:11256)
    at core.js:11230
    at core.js:1146
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepForEach (core.js:1146)
    at R3Injector.processInjectorType (core.js:11230)
```

I checked several questions about this topic in StackOverflow, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/error-when-trying-to-inject-a-service-into-an-angular-component-exception-can) but almost everywhere just the `@Injectable()` was the missing part, but in this case I use this decorator.

Any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: This looks overly complicated, I believe you can simply use the `environment ` variable imported without having to inject it. Its is also easier to add the `providedIn` property to the `@Injectable` decorator rather than adding the providers array. If the environment variable is from a remote source then simply saving it as an observable should be sufficient

Comment: The "use the environment  variable imported without having to inject it" part I think it's not working in a library. Or it is? The lib is installable from npm.

Comment: What does `model: T` constructor argument in your library `RemoteDataService` do?

Comment: @Akash in this example it's do nothing, good point. But still I think it's an important detail because some suggested solutions said fetch environment values as a constructor argument, and I don't want to do that.

Comment: I guess the problem is with your constructor argument. Angular DI needs to know the instances you want to inject in your service's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution (actually a workaround). I think this isn't an elegant way, but it's wokring.

I created an `EnvService` class what can pick up the `environment` parameter from the module, and doesn't have sideeffects with constructor attributes:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EnvService {
  public environment: any = {};

  constructor(@Inject('env') private env?: any) {
    this.environment = env ?? {};
  }
}
```

Then in my library's main module file I set up the `EnvService` instead of `RemoteDataService`:

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { DataInjectorModule } from './data-injector.module';
import { EnvService } from './services/env/env.service';

// @dynamic
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    DataInjectorModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class DataCoreModule {
  static InjectorInstance: Injector;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    DataCoreModule.InjectorInstance = injector;
  }

  public static forRoot(environment: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: DataCoreModule,
      providers: [
        EnvService,
        { provide: 'env', useValue: environment }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Finally in my `RemoteDataService` changed the `@Inject` solution to an `InjectorInstance.get(EnvService)` solution:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataInjectorModule } from '../../data-injector.module';
import { EnvService } from '../env/env.service';

// @dynamic
@Injectable()
export class RemoteDataService<T> {
  private env = DdataInjectorModule.InjectorInstance.get(EnvService);
  public type: new () => T;
  
  constructor(
    model: T,
  ) {
    this.http = DataInjectorModule.InjectorInstance.get(HttpClient);
  }

  // ...
}
```

So the `RemoteDataService`'s `constructor` attributes are untouched, but the service can access to the environment variables over the `EnvService`.

Answer (score 6):

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RemoteDataService: (?)

The error says it all. Angular can't resolve all the constructor parameters in RemoteDataService. When this service is instantiated, it expects the required parameters.

You can provide the required dependency via [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken), please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41782168/3503019) answer for  details.

But your service uses `generics` and you did not mention how you're using this service in your components, so I'd suggest you declare the providers in your components (or module will work too) and use `@Inject()` to inject different versions of this service in your component like show below (checkout [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aj2wqp?file=src/app/app.component.ts) and see the console for a log from service constructor)-

```js
import { Component, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { RemoteDataService } from "./custom/remote-data.service";

export class A {}

export class B {}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  providers: [
    { provide: "env", useValue: {} },
    {
      provide: "ARemoteDataService",
      useFactory: () => new RemoteDataService<A>(new A())
    },
    {
      provide: "BRemoteDataService",
      useFactory: () => new RemoteDataService<B>(new B())
    }
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject("ARemoteDataService")
    private aRemoteDataService: RemoteDataService<A>,
    @Inject("BRemoteDataService")
    private bRemoteDataService: RemoteDataService<B>
  ) {}
}
```

Also, not sure if you can use `@Inject()` outside constructor. But you can always use the injector to get your other dependencies (`env` in your case) -

```js
// @Inject('env') private environment: any = {};
constructor(model: T) {
this.environment = DataInjectorModule.InjectorInstance.get("env");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Angular DI is done in `constructor` in most cases. As you've written constructor like this

```
constructor(
    model: T,
  )
```

Angular thinks that you are trying to inject `T`. you should be injecting all the things you want in the constructor

```
constructor( @Inject('env') private environment) {}
```

but make sure that env is provided correctly. and even better use `InjectionToken`s for that reason

Comment: The `model` variable is used in the `RemoteDataSerivce`'s functions. It can not be deleted from constructor attributes. And in the other hand the RemoteDataService is used in other services, what used in other services and so on... so I don't want to add another constructor attribute, because it involves the upgrade of the entire applications what uses this library.

Comment: the service instance should be created by angular dependency injection, not by the custom code